# iterate path + filenames to create new file objects

Tags: python, loops, file, io

i'm working on a project which requires working with files and:

- in one of the more complicated functions, the function takes a directory argument which contains the project files
- the file names are provided as strings

  ex. file1 = 'file1.json'
  file2 = 'file2.csv'
  file3 = 'file3.csv'

I would like to:

- iterate over the files and use os.path.join to create valid paths
- iterate over these paths and use open() to create separate file objects

something like this i guess (i know it's wrong):

```py
    for file in [file1, file2, file3]:
        file_object{}.format(filename) = open(os.path.join(directory, file),'r')
        read contents of file into file object...
```

Not sure if this is practical to do... would appreciate any ideas

Comment: Use `os.listdir()` to get all the files in the directory. `for file in os.listdir(directory): file_path = os.path.join(directory, file)` and do something with `file_path`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope I understood your question correctly, you don't need the full directory to read from a file.

```
from glob import glob
##### get the files without input
files = glob('*.csv')


##or get them from user
files=['file1.json','file2.csv','file3.csv']


rs=[]
for file in files:
    with open(file,encoding='utf-8') as f:
        rs.append(f.read().splitlines())
```

Output of rs:

```
[ [line1 of file1,line2 of file1,....] ,  [line1 of file2,line2 of file2,....] ,
[line1 of file3,line2 of file3,....]   ...   ]
```